# How order an associative object by value of property of contained object in javascript

Tags: javascript, sql-order-by, associative-array

For example, for this associative object:

```
a["id1"] = { Id: "id1", Count: 15, Other: "aaa"};
a["id2"] = { Id: "id2", Count: 5, Other: "bbb" };
```

I like to have this array:

```
b[0] = { Id: "id2", Count: 5, Other: "bbb" };
b[1] = { Id: "id1", Count: 15, Other: "aaa"};
```

Comment: Er...you want to swap the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
var b = [];
for(x in a)
    b.push(a[x]);
```

Order of the elements in the array won't be guaranteed, if you want that you'll have to sort the array after. Let me know if you want help with that too.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `for in` loop to gather the objects into an array so that they can be ordered.

```
var data = [];
for(var name in object) {
  if (object.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
    data.push ( name );
  }
}
```

Then use Javascript's built in Array sorting method, passing it a function with which to compare the objects in the array.

```
//I assume you are sorting on Count
data.sort(function (a,b) { return a.Count - b.Count });
```